# How to change the data type from bytea[] to bytea of column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL. I want to change one of my column datatype from `bytea[]` to `bytea` in Postgres. I tried the following query but it is giving the error `cannot cast type bytea[] to bytea`:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN COLUMN_NAME TYPE bytea USING COLUMN_NAME::bytea;
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many elements of the array do you want to save. If it is enough to save the first element:

```
alter table table_name alter column_name type bytea using column_name[1];
```

or you can concatenate two first elements:

```
alter table table_name alter column_name type bytea using column_name[1] || column_name[2];
```

To convert all elements of the original column you need to create a function which concatenates unknown number of array elements.